# Como mudar o background da header da JTable sem retirar a borda?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Estou tentando mudar a cor do background da `header` da `JTable`.

Com esse código eu consegui:

```
public Principal() throws UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        initComponents();

        jTable.getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(new HeaderColor());

    }

static public class HeaderColor extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    public HeaderColor() {
        setOpaque(true);
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jTable, Object value, boolean selected, boolean focused, int row, int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(jTable, value, selected, focused, row, column);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255,255,255));
        return this;
    }
}
```

Esse é o resultado que esperava, porém, está sem a borda no header. Eu necessito dessa borda.

[image: imagem da JTable sem a borda no header]

Existe alguma maneira de alterar esse código de forma a inserir a borda?

Comment: Ta usando tema Nimbus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente colocar isso:

```
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jTable, Object value, boolean selected, boolean focused, int row, int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(jTable, value, selected, focused, row, column);
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        return this;
    }
```

Isso é possível porque `DefaultTableCellRenderer` é subclasse de `JLabel` [(documentação)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html). Assim sendo, o que vale para mudar a borda de um `JLabel` deve valer também para o seu `CellRenderer`.

Mais informações sobre mudar as bordas [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html).