# Como retirar a borda das Colunas do Header

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Eu não to conseguindo retirar a borda branca do **header** da **jTable**

```
public static JTable CMtable(String[] colunas, int width, int height) {
    TableColumn coluna;
    JTable tbl = new JTable();
    tbl.setBounds(0,0,width,height);
    for (int i = 0; i < colunas.length; i++) {
        coluna = new TableColumn(i);
        coluna.setHeaderValue(colunas[i]);
        tbl.addColumn(coluna);
    }
    tbl.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(tbl.getWidth()*1/10);
    tbl.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(tbl.getWidth()*5/10);
    tbl.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(tbl.getWidth()*4/10);
    tbl.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    tbl.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
    tbl.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
    tbl.setShowHorizontalLines(false);
    tbl.setShowVerticalLines(false); 

    tbl.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", 1, 14));
    tbl.setBackground(BdoColor.CINZA);
    tbl.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Tahoma", 1, 14));
    tbl.getTableHeader().setOpaque(false);
    tbl.getTableHeader().setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    tbl.getTableHeader().setBackground(BdoColor.CINZA);
    tbl.setAlignmentX(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    tbl.getTableHeader().setAlignmentY(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    tbl.setRowHeight(25, 1);
    tbl.setBackground(BdoColor.CINZA);

    return tbl;
}
```

O resultado apos executar é o seguinte:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que eu queria que não tivesse as bordas brancas, já tentei mexer com o setBorder mas não obtive resultado.

Aguardo resposta!, qualquer dica de estudo seria bem vinda! Valeu

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como mudar o background da header da JTable sem retirar a borda?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163398/como-mudar-o-background-da-header-da-jtable-sem-retirar-a-borda)

Answer (score 0):

Importe:

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory
```

e tente:

```
tbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY,1));
```